# Was Laz near Pribram at any time situated in the Sudetenland?

Tags: czechoslovakia

Was Laz near Pribram at any time situated in the Sudetenland? 
Are there any public records relating to Laz in the 1920s still surviving? I think my father, Josef Teinor, was born there.

Comment: What has your research shown? Seems like this should be easy to verify on google maps. [Sudetenland](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://skepticism-images.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/jreviews/sudetenland_map.jpg&imgrefurl=http://skepticism.org/timeline/october-history/9371-germany-starts-annexation-sudetenland.html&h=420&w=800&tbnid=W0sWfbw7cTqBNM:&q=sudetenland&tbnh=105&tbnw=200&usg=AI4_-kSebZ7Q-ixVOAcpsraAxmNLNxvJ6g&vet=12ahUKEwjmnP65wqveAhWNuVMKHUCaAkkQ_B0wHnoECAgQCQ..i&docid=HngVlVpnKSF5qM&itg=1&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwjmnP65wqveAhWNuVMKHUCaAkkQ_B0wHnoECAgQCQ)

Answer (score 2):

If you define Sudetenland as the parts of today's Czechia that were annexed by Germany in 1938, then no, Láz was not part of Sudetenland.

According to [Czech Wikipedia](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1z_(okres_P%C5%99%C3%ADbram)), Láz was part of:

> - 1939 země česká, Oberlandrat Tábor, politický i soudní okres Příbram[7]
> - 1942 země česká, Oberlandrat Praha, politický i soudní okres Příbram[8]

Translation:

> - 1939 Bohemia, Oberlandrat Tábor, political and judicial district Příbram
> - 1942 Bohemia, Oberlandrat Praha, political and judicial district Příbram

In other words, Láz was part of the Protectorate of Bohemia and Moravia, so it wasn't part of Sudetenland.